# Firebase ordering and retrieving the index for a specific record

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, nosql

I'm using Firebase 2.4.2. I have a database as follows:

```
  "items": {
    "item1": {
      "details": {
        "name": "item 1",
        "rate": 5
    },

    "item2": {
      "details": {
        "name": "item 2",
        "rate": "4"
      }
    }

    "item3": {
      "details": {
        "name": "item 3",
        "rate": "6"
      }
    }
  }
```

I have thousands of items and don't want to load them all in a table. Rather, I'd like to load the top10 along with the item that user has clicked on. So, if you are in the page: `/items/details/item2`, I'd like you see the top10 items in the database (based on their rates) and the `item2` in a table. I'd also like to show **the index of `item2` in the ordered list**.

```
ind id     rate
1   item56 100
2   item33 98
...
143 item2  13
```

What we do normally -if the bandwidth is not issue- is to retrieve all data as follows (e.g. using AngularFire)

```
var ref = fbutil.ref('items').orderByChild('details/rate');
 return $firebaseArray(ref);
```

However, I'd like to order them, retrieve the top10, and then retrieve the `item2` (in this case) and its index (`143`) based on its rate.

How would I do that?

Answer (score -1):

```
// For getting top 10
var ref = fbutil.ref('items').orderByChild('details/rate').limitToFirst(10);
return $firebaseArray(ref); 

// For getting single
var ref = fbutil.ref('items').orderByChild('details/rate').equalTo(13);
var singleItem = $firebaseObject(ref);
```

Checkout the following link to see what methods [firebase.database.Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) class supports.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference

Comment: Thanks Zura, but this doesn't answer my question. The problem is not to get the top10 and a specific item. The problem is to get the index of that specific item in the database, based on its `rate` (based on the same metric used to sort those top10 items) without retrieving the whole data from the database.

Comment: Understood. May I know why do you want this index, What is your final purpose?

Comment: Imagine you have thousands of items. I don't want to load them everytime someone clicks on an item. Rather, I'd like to show the top items plus the  ranking of the current item based on its rate.